# Chai recognition in Webstorm 7.0.2

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, webstorm, chai

I want to get into testing node.js applications via mocha and chai.

I got the following code snippet modified from the mocha website:

```
var expect = require( 'chai' ).expect;


describe('Array', function(){


    describe('#indexOf()', function(){
        it('should return -1 when not present', function(){
            expect([1,2,3].indexOf(4) ).to.equal(-1);
        });
    });
});
```

Well, everything is ok, the test passes but the `.expect` is not recognized by Webstorm. The libary chai-DefinitelyTyped is installed.

Weired fact: when I change `require( 'chai' )` to `require( 'chai.js' )`
 or `require( 'chaijs' )` the expect is recognized by the IDE, but ofc the tests won't run anymore.

Am I missing something obvious or is this a bug?

Comment: please see http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5504687#5504687 for possible workarounds

Comment: I'm also seeing this behavior, and have chai-DefinitelyTyped installed. Seems to be related to requiring modules at a deeper level than the top.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that downloading the typings for the specific libraries tends to sovle this problem. In Webstorm you can do this like so:

1. Head over to:
   Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries
2. User the **[Download...]** button and select the necessary framework from the list (in my case, `chai-as-promised`'s eventually and other keywords were not being recognised, so I have selected this one).
3. **[Download and Install]** the types.

[image: Webstorm Preferences - Libraries tab]

*I have also had to remove the types, restart the IDE and add them again previously for the IntelliSense to kick-in.*